# How to turn a translations table into YAML translation files in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml, translation

My app is currently using the gem `i18n-active_record` for translations, storing them in a table `translations` which has more than 5000 records.

To improve performance, I want to move the translations to YAML files, e.g. `en.yml` and `ar.yml`.

I tried `File.open(Rails.root+'config/locales/en.yml', 'w') {|f| f.write translation.to_yaml }` but the output generated is the following:

```
    raw_attributes:
    id: 1
    locale: en
    key: footer.new_car_make
    value: New %{title} Cars
    interpolations: 
    is_proc: 0
    created_at: &4 2012-08-15 06:25:59.000000000 Z
    updated_at: &5 2012-08-15 06:25:59.000000000 Z
```

Is there any easy way to make the conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this (I don't have any DB backed Rails Translations to try this)

```
def assign(parts, value, data)
  key, *rest = parts
  if rest.empty?
    data[key] = value
  else
    data[key] ||= {}
    assign(rest, value, data[key])
  end
end

translations = {}
Translation.all.each do |translation|
  path = [translation.locale] + translation.key.split(".")
  assign(path, translation.value, translations)
end

File.write("translations.yml", translations.to_yaml)
```

Of course you can modify to only export the translations of a single locale or specific keys (by changing the `all` to a `where` query).

The code works as following:

It iterates all the Translations, and builds a hash with all the translations.
The key `footer.new_car_make` of the `en` translation will end up in a nested hash like:

```
{
  "en" => {
    "footer" => {
      "new_car_make" => "Whatever text you have in the DB"
    }
  }
}
```

and then this hash is saved as YAML format in a file.

The `assign` method is called with the full key (it contains the locale as well) represented as an array (`['en', 'footer', 'new_car_make']`) and deconstructs into a head (first value in the array) and the rest (remaining parts).
If the remaining part is empty, it means we've reached the last element and can assign the value, otherwise we add a nested hash and recurse.

You can try this in the console (just copy paste it). As mentioned this might not run right out of the box, let me know if you have troubles.

Comment: can you explain data variable what is it doing

Comment: I don’t see you using the `translations` variable anywhere, so I believe this is just essentially doing `{}.to_yaml` at the moment.

Comment: I see. My error. Will fix.
I changed the variable name when cleaning up and missed this occurence.

Comment: If I’m reading this right, the `data` inside of the `Translation.all.each` loop should actually be `translations`.

Comment: I don’t have a good way to run this, but I think it’ll work! +1 from me